# Requisições ajax encadeadas

Tags: php, jquery

Meu objetivo é transmitir uma requisição para um php, e posteriormente retornar listar dados em um modal[bootstrap 5], para após realizar um UPDATE.

Encontrei algumas soluções para resolver a questão com [session, variável global, entre outras... porém achei um pouco "gambiarra" o resultado final];

É possível fazer algo neste sentido? Enviar uma requisição, obter uma resposta, e encadear outra requisição com ajax? Ou o conceito fica master gambiarra!

Obrigado amigos

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'x.php',
        data: {getIdUpdate: getId},
        success: function(response){
          alert(response);
          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'y.php',
            data: dados,
            success: function(response2){
              alert(response2);
            }
          });
        }//success
      });//ajax
```

Answer (score 0):

Se voce consegui alterar o código da pagina que esta acessando `x.php`, o certo seria ja enviar a variável `dados` junto com a primeira requisição `{getIdUpdate: getId, dados}` e tratar tudo junto.  Agora se esta acessando um api externo ou algo do tipo, não vejo um problema com a sua função.

Não e difícil seguir o código com so duas requisições, mais se no futuro vai adicionar outras requisições neste *promise chain* acho que fica mais fácil de entender usando o formato abaixo.

```
const funcao1 = (getId) => {
  return $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'x.php',
     data: {getIdUpdate: getId}        
  });
}

const funcao2 = (dados) => {
  return $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'y.php',
     data: dados,  
  });
}

funcao1(id).then((resultado1) => {
    alert(resultado1);
    return funcao2(dados);
 }).then((resultado2) => {
    alert(resultado2);
 });
```